# Can I isolate scope for a div?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a page and a model on my scope `$scope.model = { ... };`
I bind values on my page with values on the model which is nice. I have an address nested somewhere in that model, for the sake of this example lets say

> $scope.model = { visits : [{date : ..., addresses : [{ ... }, ...]},
>   ...], ...};

I need to write all the information of the first visits first address somewhere in a div. I know i can type all the fields like this `model.visits[0].addresses[0].Zip` etc. but there are like 5 fields in `model.visits[0].addresses[0]` that i need to output. I figured, there most be an easier way? I considered putting a

```
<div ng-init="a = model.visits[0].addresses[0]">{{a.Zip}}...</div>
```

and then just access all properties like that. What i really want though, it not to create a new property on the scope called `a` unless i can narrow the scope for `a` to just that one div.

Is that possible somehow?

Clarification: I know i can probably redo my model or move the data up on model itself, but this is just something I've run into multiple times and i would just really want to know if there is a solution to a problem like this.

Comment: May be better off creating an address directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a tiny directive that creates a new scope on the elements you want:

```
...
angular.module('yourApp').directive('newScope', function () {
    return {scope: true};
});
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<div ng-init="tmp=model.visits[0].addresses[0]" new-scope>{{tmp.Zip}}...</div>
```

Now, the `tmp` property will be attached to the new scope created by the `newScope` directive and will not affect the parent scope.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/XWQ93/)**.

Comment: great answer, and i love the fiddle too